# Returning a (recursively) altered list?

Tags: python, list, recursion

I'm looking to take a list `list=[3,2,1,3,2,1]` and for every item recursively check if the item is a value `a` and if so replace that value with `b` in a copy of `thelist`, and return that copy. 
This is my code so far:

```
def replace(list,a,b):
    #base case 1: list is empty
    if list==[]:
        return list
    #case 1: the first character is a
    elif list[0] == a:
        list[0] = b
        return replace(list[1:],a,b)
    #case 2: the first character is not a
    elif list[0]!=a:
        return replace(list[1:],a,b)
    return list
```

My issue is that my (**printed each recursion, the print statements were removed for shortness**) output from this code looks like this:

```
[3,2,1,3,2,1]
[2,1,3,2,1]
[4,3,2,1]
[3,2,1]
[2,1]
[4]
```

and the output that I'm looking for is:

```
[3,2,4,3,2,4]
```

I'm not sure how to get said output.

Comment: You need a loop to iterate over the elementos of the list and check every element = a

Comment: Is there a way to do it without a for-loop?

Comment: jjb: That's a different question.

Comment: what values of `a` & `b` do you use to call the function `replace`?

Comment: recursion is not really a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the first element when call replace again. Just append the first element to the front of result.

```
def replace(thelist,a,b):
    #base case 1: thelist is empty
    if thelist==[]:
        return thelist
    #case 1: the first character is a
    elif thelist[0] == a:
        thelist[0] = b
    return thelist[:1] + replace(thelist[1:], a, b)


print replace([3,2,1,3,2,1], 1, 4)
```

Answer (score 3):

Same result witout recursion :

```
def replace_list(thelist,a,b):
    return [ b if l == a else l for l in thelist ]

print replace_list([3,2,1,3,2,1], 1, 4)
```

Output :

```
[3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4]
```

Comment: it will be great to also rename parameters into something like `elements`, `condition_value`, `replacement_value`